# What is the maximum charge current and discharge current of R5460 Series IC?

Tags: batteries, current, protection, charging

I am using "R5460N214AF" IC for 2 cell Li-Ion battery protection. According to datasheet, excess discharge current threshold is 0.2 V and excess charge current threshold is -0.2 V.

I would like to understand these voltage thresholds in terms of currents. Some one please explain how to understand max charge current and discharge current supported by the IC.

I am attaching the datasheet for your reference.

https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/792/r5460-e-1085730.pdf

Let me know if I am not clear and please help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Max current supported by the IC is 4.0µA.

> Supply current (At normal mode) Typ. 4.0µA
>
> Standby current Typ. 1.2µA (A/ D/ E version)

---

Those parameters

```
excess discharge current threshold is 0.2 V 
excess charge current threshold is -0.2 V.
```

are used for triggering the transistor switches connected to the IC. Usually, they are partnered with the time parameters.

```
Over-charge detector Output Delay 1.0s
Over-discharge detector Output Delay 128ms
```

If the load takes more than 0.2V at 128ms or the charger gives 0.2V at 1.0s you need a higher sensitive IC protector.

Answer (score 0):

Good question . It seems to be a Ricoh secret as to what value is used for the current sense R internally between the two DFETs . But there are 3 threshold options at least.

(1) +/-0.4V +- 40mV
(2) +/-0.2V +- 30mV
(3) +/-0.1V. +-30mV

So Imax =0.2V / R? Mystery

If you must know contact your distributor or get a sample.

### Opinion

This is an IC designed to protect Lithium batteries from over charging not maximize charge current at the expense of aging.  So there are 3 threshold voltages offered 0.1V, 0.2V and 0.4V which is used in both polarities of current.

Looking at the Absolute Max Power Spec's I can speculate that the max current must be less that the abs. max power dissipation  of the tiny part.

Given that Pmax =  500 mW   and Vth comparator threshold options are +/-{0.1,0.2,0.4V}  Imax **must be less than the following** calculation, but how much depends on the internal current sense R

Given  Pmax/Vth=Imax   is an absolute limit and ,
may be actually less than this

150mW/200mV = 750mA
150mW/100mV = 1.5A
150mW/400mV = 375mA

Comment: Hi Tony, How can we design the protection circuit with this IC without understanding it's maximum current capabilities. Understanding current limits is important to choose power mosfets in the circuit. Please help.

Comment: Get a sample , ask distributor or Rep to get answers

Comment: But Imax must be less than Pmax/Vth=150mW/200mV <750mA or 150mW/100mV =1.5A or <150mW/400mV = 375mA